Trying to access shared external drive attached to Ubuntu Desktop in Windows 11
I am trying to access an external drive which is attached to Ubuntu Desktop from a Windows 11 PC. I want to access this on Windows 11 attached to Ubuntu desktop, Disk /dev/sdd: 2.73 TiB, 3000592498688 bytes, 5860532224 sectors Disk model: My Book 25ED. I can ping both IPs Ubuntu and Windows 11 machine from each other.
I see an external drive attached in Ubuntu under Files. I also read in a forum and mounted the external drive as per instructions, however once try to connect to the external drive on Ubuntu with IP:192.168.1.187 with \192.168.1.187 I see no contents on drive. Whereas drives has files I was using it before on Windows 11.
Output of sudo fdisk -l :
Disk /dev/loop0: 73.87 MiB, 77459456 bytes, 151288 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 74.27 MiB, 77881344 bytes, 152112 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop2: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop3: 269.77 MiB, 282873856 bytes, 552488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop4: 10.72 MiB, 11239424 bytes, 21952 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop5: 273.68 MiB, 286969856 bytes, 560488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop6: 11.11 MiB, 11649024 bytes, 22752 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop7: 505.09 MiB, 529625088 bytes, 1034424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: Patriot P210 102
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 304EBC23-C3C6-4D4E-AB20-2B9CE69BF50B

Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    2203647    2201600     1G EFI System
/dev/sda2  2203648 2000406527 1998202880 952.8G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/loop8: 91.69 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop9: 10.54 MiB, 11051008 bytes, 21584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop10: 10.76 MiB, 11280384 bytes, 22032 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop11: 38.83 MiB, 40714240 bytes, 79520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop12: 44.3 MiB, 46448640 bytes, 90720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop14: 568 KiB, 581632 bytes, 1136 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop13: 500 KiB, 512000 bytes, 1000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sdb: 223.57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model:                 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7feeb02c

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 468858879 468856832 223.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdc: 931.51 GiB, 1000204885504 bytes, 1953525167 sectors
Disk model: Portable        
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdcf54351

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *       64 1953520128 1953520065 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdd: 2.73 TiB, 3000592498688 bytes, 5860532224 sectors
Disk model: My Book 25ED    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1625C9CF-6C48-4DA6-8625-A39BEA81698E

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1   2048 5860530175 5860528128  2.7T Microsoft basic data



With the disk connected and mounted, run sudo fdisk -l, copy and paste the output editing your post.

Thanks here it is: I just edited my post with output

I want to access this on win 11 attched to ubuntu desktop , Disk /dev/sdd: 2.73 TiB, 3000592498688 bytes, 5860532224 sectors Disk model: My Book 25ED

Steps to Access a Shared External Drive on Ubuntu from Windows 11:

Ensure Samba is Installed on Ubuntu:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install samba


2.Edit Samba Configuration:
Add the shared drive to /etc/samba/smb.conf:
[SharedDrive]
path = /media/username/external_drive
browseable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = yes
force user = username

3.Restart Samba Service:
sudo systemctl restart smbd

4.Get Ubuntu’s IP Address:
ip addr show

5.Access from Windows 11:
Open File Explorer.
Type \<Ubuntu_IP> in the address bar and press Enter.
Locate and access the shared drive.

Hi ! by username mean username i use to login to ubuntu desktop ?

One tru to access \192.168.1.187 My Book Ip asked for username and password after typing in my username password it says not accessible you might not have permissoions
